# CSS grid gap between rows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn how to use grid layout. I need to make my grid take the entire page, but for some reason, there is an extra space between the navigation bar (1st row) and the 2nd row. how do I get rid of the space so that the only space remaining between 1st and 2nd row is the grid-gap I specified.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toYGk.jpg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#grid-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  grid-column: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-row: 60px auto auto auto 30px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav nav" "top-post top-post post-2 post-3" "top-post top-post post-4 post-5" "newsletter newsletter newsletter newsletter" "ft ft ft ft";
}

.nav-bar {
  grid-area: nav;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.website-title {
  width: 40%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.nav-bar-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 60%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav-bar-item {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.main-post {
  grid-area: top-post;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#post2 {
  grid-area: post-2;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#post3 {
  grid-area: post-3;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#post4 {
  grid-area: post-4;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#post5 {
  grid-area: post-5;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.newsletter {
  grid-area: newsletter;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: ft;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="grid-layout">
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <div class="website-title">Title</div>
      <ul class="nav-bar-list">
        <li class="nav-bar-item">Home</li>
        <li class="nav-bar-item">Blog</li>
        <li class="nav-bar-item">About</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="main-post">
      <div class="text-gradient">
        <a href="#">
          <h4>Main Post Here</h4>
        </a>
        <p>Main Post Summary here</p>
        <a href="#" class="main-post-button">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="post" id="post2">
      <a href="#" class="link">
        <div class="text-gradient">
          <h4>Post 2 Here</h4>
          <p>Post 2 subtitle</p>
        </div>
      </a>

    </section>
    <section class="post" id="post3">
      <a href="#" class="link">
        <div class="text-gradient">
          <h4>Post 3 Here</h4>
          <p>Post 3 subtitle</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </section>
    <section class="post" id="post4">
      <a href="#" class="link">
        <div class="text-gradient">
          <h4>Post 4 Here</h4>
          <p>Post 4 subtitle</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </section>
    <section class="post" id="post5">
      <a href="#" class="link">
        <div class="text-gradient">
          <h4>Post 5 Here</h4>
          <p>Post 5 subtitle</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </section>
    <section class="newsletter">
      <form action="#">
        <h5>Subscribe to our Newsletter</h5>
        <div class="newsletter-container">
          <div class="newsletter-element">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="newsletter-element">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="mail" required>
          </div>
          <div class="newsletter-element">
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- newletter container -->
      </form>
    </section>
    <footer id="footer">
      <div>
        <p>All Right Reserved</p>
      </div>
    </footer>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For extras space you need to changes in margin & padding only.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-bar{
    grid-area: nav;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid red;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

you have the `padding:10px` in your css code, the `padding` attribute puts some margin over were the `.nav-bar` tag is applied, you have to change it to `padding:0px` or remove it completely

Comment: i removed it;however, there is still a lot of space between nav bar and posts below. 
also the footer doesn't stay all the way on the bottom

Comment: @eliranno try doing `top:0px` `bottom:0px’

Comment: still see the same issue

Comment: I basically want the row to end where the red border line is. I think this extra space is the remaining of the 1st row height, but I dont know how to get rid of it

Comment: issue still exists.

Comment: try `grid-gap:0px;`

Comment: I unfortunately cannot help you any further, and i cannot deduce the error that is happening in the css code

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about your "div" elements, ´´´<div id="grid-layout> ´´´ in HTML is working as the body of the code, I tried some solutions about this but I am also kınd a new in this too.

Answer (score 0):

it was a typo instead of "grid-template-column" "grid-template-row" I had "grid-column" "grid-row"